# error 404 due to mishandling of a war file, maybe?

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, tomcat, cxf, war

I'm trying to deploy my java project on Tomcat via a war file, but I got **404-error** when I enter the above URL in my favorite navigator. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/).

To deploy my project, I puted the War file under **${Tomcat}/webapp**.

Here is my **sun-jaxws.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
  version="2.0">
  <endpoint
      name="projetServices"
      implementation="com.bh.services.Service"
      url-pattern="/service"/>
</endpoints>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, 
Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**URL :** localhost:8088/projetServices/service

**Here is my project architecture:**

[image]

Please how can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Are you sure that the path: `/projetServices/service` is correct?

Comment: Look at the **sun-jaxws.xml** please

Comment: It's been a while since I've used jax-ws config, not sure how it's exposing web service path. Is your .war file named projetServices.war? Also take a look at the logs, are there any deployment errors?

Comment: Yes, but in which log file can I find the above error please ?

Comment: Edit your question and past the actual error and some more relevant details from the logs.

Comment: I can not find the error in the log files generated